# psql , creating stored procedure - converting string to schema type

Tags: postgresql

I have a stored producedure that does this, `my_schema` is the name of the current schema I'm using in my db.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE myprocedure(data TEXT) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
   DECLARE
      my_variable my_schema.my_table%ROWTYPE;
      BEGIN
          SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table WHERE oid=3;
      END;
$$;
```

But, I need this to be a bit more generic, and I'd like to use this for any schema I create  in my db, so, I'd like to pass in the `schema` name instead like this, so that I won't have to create a procedure for every schema created in the future:

> note I've used angle brackets for syntax I'm not sure of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE myprocedure(data TEXT, my_schema_name <SOME_TYPE>) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
  DECLARE
          my_variable <my_schema_name>.my_table%ROWTYPE;
          BEGIN
              SELECT * FROM <my_schema_name>.my_table WHERE oid=3;
          END;
    $$;
```

and then call it like this:

```
CALL myprocedure('SOMETHIGN', <MY_SCHEMA_NAME>);
```

what is the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `record` type for a generic record, and you use dynamic SQL for the query. Here is an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE x(schema_name text) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   q record;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
              'SELECT * FROM %I.data WHERE id = 1',
              schema_name
           ) INTO q;

   RAISE NOTICE '%', q.id;
END;$$;
```